# Element UI - Custom label form select component

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

Using the library `element-ui` whose documentation is [here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select), I'd like to know wether it is possible to display a custom label once an option has been selected for a `select` component.

In other word, is it possible to display a `slot` instead of just one word for the label `:label="item.label"`

https://jsfiddle.net/q4c3m860/

I could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with javascript in the `:label` property, for example, to change the selected label to 'foo':

```
  <span style="float: left">{{ item.value === value6 ? 'foo' : item.label }}</span>
```

Here's your fiddle updated:  https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/j1mwnpLf/1/

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. It shors how to customize options values, not selected value

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same problem and could not find a proper solution neither in the docs nor by googling. So I checked the implementation of `<el-select>`.

You can change the label of the selected value by changing the label prop in the `<el-option>` and having different content rendered in the default slot.
The original implementation, uses an `<input>` to display its current value, which means you can't use html to render something.

Here's your fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/a4n9up6j/

If you want to display some fancy html you would need to wrap the select and use some custom logic.